# Unable to infer enough type information about _; type annotations or generic parameter binding required

Tags: rust

```
trait Bar {
    fn bar(&self);
}
enum Foo<T: Bar> {
    F1,
    F2(T)
}
struct Something;
impl Bar for Something {
    fn bar(&self) {
    }
}
fn main() {
    let a = Foo::F2(Something); //<== this works fine.
    let b = Foo::F1; //<== gives a compilation error.
}
```

Compilation error E0282: Unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required.

I understand why the compiler is complaining but can't seem to figure out how to do this without having to assign a type to T in the F1 case.

Comment: *without having to assign a type to T* — Why don't you want to assign a concrete type to `T`?

Comment: Well I meant in the case of F1 I don't need the type T so it seems pointless to do so. If there is no way to do this I can live with assigning a type to T in all cases.

Comment: You can specify a default value for `T`, but it seems to be buggy with inference: [This](http://is.gd/kX0awA) doesn't work, but [this](http://is.gd/7WU1qN) does.

Comment: Ah, that's just a not yet stable feature: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29101, works now: http://is.gd/GIiHHP

Comment: Thanks for the answer but default is not what I was looking for. I followed Shepmaster adivce and solved it like this http://is.gd/lz8TRr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Enum variants* do not have their own type. There is only the type of the enum itself. Check out this example:

```
enum Thing<T> {
    One,
    Two(T),
}

fn main() {
    let a = Thing::One;
    let b = Thing::Two(true);
}
```

The type of `b` is a `Thing<bool>`. The type has no mention of `Two`. The same thing needs to happen for `a`, but there's nothing that the compiler can use to infer the value of `T`, so you have to provide it explicitly:

```
let a = Thing::One::<u8>;
```

And an even-smaller example is to use an enum that is built-in and very familiar — `Option`:

```
fn main() {
    // let a = None;
    let a = None::<u8>;
    let b = Some(true);
}
```

> I don't need the type T so it seems pointless to do so.

Let's dive in a bit deeper. An enum takes up the space of the max of all the variants (plus a wee bit to tell them apart):

```
enum Foo {
    One(u64),
    Two(u8),
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<u64>());
    // 8
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<u8>());
    // 1
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Foo>());
    // 16
}
```

Also, all variants of the same enum take up the same amount of space:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Some(true);
    let b = None::<bool>;

    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&a));
    // 2
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&b));
    // 2
}
```

This helps lead us to the realization that **not all `None`s are the same**:

```
fn main() {
    let a = None::<u8>;
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&a));
    // 2

    let b = None::<u64>;
    println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&b));
    // 16
}
```

Thus it *is* important to know exactly what kind of `None` you have. This extends to every kind of enum and variant.

Comment: Did not know you could type annotate None.  This just saved me a big headache!