# Sum array along dimension

Tags: arrays, sum, rust

In many languages (Fortran, Matlab/Octave, Julia, etc) an expression like `sum(array,n)` will sum the values of an array along the n:th dimension and outputting an array of one lower dimensionality. Is there something equivalent in Rust?

I tried:

```
fn main() {
    let arr1: [f64; 5] = [1.1, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5555];
    println!("this {}", arr1.iter().sum())
}
```

with this error:

```
error[E0282]: unable to infer enough type information about `_`
 --> src/main.rs:3:37
  |
3 |     println!("this {}", arr1.iter().sum())
  |                                     ^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
<std macros>:2:27: 2:58 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
src/main.rs:3:5: 3:43 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
  |
  = note: type annotations or generic parameter binding required
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have to explicitly specify type of the elements:

```
println!("this {}", arr1.iter().sum::<f64>())
```

You were very close :)

---

Another option that were suggested by @E_net4 is to use separate binding:

```
let res: f64 = arr1.iter().sum();
println!("this {}", res)
```

Comment: I'm using `rustc 1.7.0` from the Ubuntu apt-repositories, and get: `test.rs:19:29: 19:34 error: use of unstable library feature 'iter_arith': bounds recently changed (see issue #27739)`.

Comment: @JonatanÖström you should update! Right now, 1.12.1 is the newest, and it represents about 30 additional weeks of work applied to the compiler; including better error messages.

Comment: I installed it on this machine just an hour ago, so I guess I should use some other channel then.

Comment: [Rustup](https://www.rustup.rs/) is one of the best ways to get the Rust compiler and other useful resources. Do try it out. :)

Comment: @E_net4 Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: @Shepmaster I installed a newer version of Rust, so the specific example works. But the question was more general, I need to do this for higher dimensional arrays, at least two dims.

Answer (score 1):

The "unable to infer enough type information about `_`" error message is explained in a few other questions. See [Error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37401681/1233251) and [Unable to infer enough type information about _; type annotations or generic parameter binding required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001546/unable-to-infer-enough-type-information-about-type-annotations-or-generic-par). Basically, it means that the compiler doesn't have enough information to specify all type parameters in a function or a data type.

**Nevertheless**, this particular case may arouse some confusion: why can't `Iterator.sum()` just infer the resulting sum's type to the iterator's `Item`? By supposedly adding up `f64`s, we'd be expecting `f64` as an outcome, right? Well, the method `sum` is actually defined like this:

```
fn sum<S>(self) -> S 
    where S: Sum<Self::Item>
```

Where `S` implements another kind of `sum` function (see [`trait Sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Sum.html)) that takes an iterator:

```
pub trait Sum<A = Self> {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self where I: Iterator<Item=A>;
}
```

This trait gives us the freedom to sum numbers and references to numbers alike:

```
static MAGIC_CODE: u32 = 0xDEADBEEF;
static BLAND_CODE: u32 = 0x1234ABCD;

fn main() {

    let sum1: u32 = vec![MAGIC_CODE, BLAND_CODE] // vec! infers to Vec<u32>
        .into_iter().sum();

    let sum2 = vec![&MAGIC_CODE, &BLAND_CODE] // vec! infers to Vec<&u32>
        .into_iter().sum::<u32>();


    assert_eq!(sum1, sum2);
}
```

On the other hand, this also means that the definition of a sum becomes more loose: any other data type implementing `Sum<u32>` (or `Sum<&u32>`) could take its place in the code above, which leads to the aforementioned ambiguity. For the purpose of demonstration, this code also compiles:

```
use std::iter::Sum;

struct Accumulator(bool);

impl Sum<u32> for Accumulator {
    fn sum<I: Iterator<Item = u32>>(mut iter: I) -> Self {
        Accumulator(iter.any(|v| v != 0))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sum3: Accumulator = {
        let data = vec![MAGIC_CODE, BLAND_CODE];

        data.into_iter().sum()
    };

    assert!(sum3.0);
}
```

[Full code on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4687ebe37e88a2c996208501102aab7c&version=stable&backtrace=0).